# Are super and hyper key modifier permitted in major/minor modes?

Tags: keymap, coding-conventions

I looked to `(info "(elisp)Key Binding Conventions")` and `(info "(elisp)Keymaps and Minor Modes")` and `(info "(elisp)Major Mode Conventions")` and didn't found any restriction to use `H-` and `s-` modifier in modes.

I heavily relay on `s-` (super) key as user customization and recently found that in Magit:

```
commit 29ff1ec6a0f65caf5c9c5bf4869015946f12f7aa
Author: Jonas Bernoulli <jonas@bernoul.li>
Date:   2016-09-07 17:42:25 +0200

magit-mode-map: bind S-tab to magit-section-cycle-global

It appears this was always the intention.  Keep the bindings
for s-tab and backtab, in case someone actually uses those.
```

I think it is illegal to define any `H-` or `s-` key binding as that can surprise users.

Are super and hyper key modifier permitted in major/minor modes?

BTW I opened issue: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3195

Comment: "illegal"? As in the Emacs police will arrest you?

Comment: I doubt you can generalize this. Exwm is an example where it would be useful for the mode to use these modifiers.  Starterkits are another example, though arguably no modes.